# How do I detect my iPhone tilting upwards?

Tags: ios, core-motion, swift4

I'm trying to print a statement when CoreMotion detects when the iPhone tilts upwards. I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. This is what I have right now:

```
if manager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue) {
    [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
    print("TILTED!!")
    }
  }
}
```

TILTED!! is not being printed so I don't know if there's something wrong with the code when I tilt my phone up and it's not working. Thanks!

Comment: So what’s the problem with the code you have?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I tilt my device up, "TILTED!!" is not being printed